# Inserting Millions of Rows from another table

Tags: sql, bigdata

Faster way to insert rows into a table from a select statement and insert into?

```
Insert into PartyMain
Select [PermID]
      ,[IsOptOut]
      ,[UpdatedOn]
      ,[FK_DataSource]
 From PartyMain
```

with 6M rows is taking > 4 minutes

Comment: around 4 minutes for 6 million rows isn't too bad... around approx. 20,000 per second. How long were you expecting it to take? What is the max theoretical throughput of your I/O subsystem?

Comment: That's 25,000 insertions per second, are you sure it's so slow? Possibly what will matter here are the DB's tuning parameters, such as the way it allocates extents, builds indexes, load factors, etc.

Comment: I agree with Mitch it doesnt sound too bad.  It might be better to look whether or not this is really necessary. What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, it isn't too bad, but I was wondering if there was some "magical" trick that could improve insertion performance. I'm looking at the need to insert billions of records and at this speed 1B = 11+ hours and wanted to see what I could to do improve load time.

Answer (score 1):

insert via select is the fastest way i can think of to insert data.  You might be able make improvements in you app work flow, however.

I imagine have some sort of button in an app that kicks off the process.  Instead of doing the insert when a user tells the app to (Im making that assumption), can you have a process that runs every X seconds that does the transfer? Or alternatively check every X seconds and if the number of rows to transfer is greater than Y, run the transfer...So in other words, dont wait until there are  6 million rows.

Edit-  another options might be [database triggers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any indexes on PartyMain? If yes, you may want to

1. Drop Indexes
2. Insert Rows
3. Recreate Indexes

that might improve the performance.

Also - are you sure you reading from PartyMain and Inserting into PartyMain?

Comment: Good Idea!  I'll try that to see if any improvements are made.

Comment: @Marty - great! I'm looking forward to see if this works for you.